# How to Merge 2 Tables Tentatively Using Replace With Some Unique Data

Tags: mysql, performance, merge

I'm trying to merge two tables into a single table. Using the example of the tables below I need to merge table B's Purchase_Date into Table A's blank Purchase_Date. Table A has an email associated with the purchase date and in table A the email is unique. However, in table B there are many email addresses and they're not unique. When I merge the two tables together I need the most recent or greatest date from table B to go into table A.

For performance reasons table A has ~33.5k rows and table B has ~550k rows.

```
Table A
Email           Purchase_Date
-----------     ---------------
test@test.ca    
test2@test.ca   
test3@test.ca

Table B
Email           Purchase_Date
-----------     ---------------
test@test.ca    2016-08-01 0:00:00
test@test.ca    2016-08-03 0:00:00
test2@test.ca   2016-08-13 0:00:00
test2@test.ca   2016-08-14 0:00:00
test2@test.ca   2016-08-15 0:00:00
test3@test.ca   2016-08-27 0:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `update` with a `join` and a subquery to get the `max` date:

```
update tablea a
join (
   select email, max(purchase_date) purchase_date
   from tableb 
   group by email
) b on a.email = b.email
set a.purchase_date = b.purchase_date
```

Comment: so long as you scrutinize it constantly for the typical gotchas for max

Answer (score 0):

For recent or greatest date from table B,There is a very useful Ranking function in SQL SERVER & ORACLE, following:

```
WITH GreatestDate AS(
SELECT Purchase_Date, Email,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Purchase_Date  DESC) AS rownum
FROM B
)

SELECT * FROM GreatestDate WHERE rownum=1
```

Then merge to Table A;

What a pity , mysql is not support those Ranking functions.

I have the same problem , an idea put forward in the discussion.